# Show a div when loading a page depending on a value

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working with Joomla and PHP and I have the following problem:

I have this DIV:

```
<div id="buypdf" style="margin-left:0px; display:none;">
    <form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="prrrrfff@gmail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $item->name; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $item->price; ?>">
        <button name="submit" id="buy_pdf" class="button" style="margin-left:5px;" type="submit">Buy pdf!</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

And it works pretty fine. I had that 'display:none;' in order to set it to 'block' or 'show' if the category of the item is > 38, for example.

But it is not working.

I've read answers from similar questions and I added this:

```
<script>
   $(window).load(function() {
       $("#buypdf").show();
   });
</script>
```

This:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#buypdf").show();
   });
</script>
```

And even this:

```
$(function() {
   document.id('#buypdf').setStyle('display','block');
});
```

But nothing is working. I'm just trying this in order to see that it works but what I want to do is something like the following:

```
<script>
   $(window).load(function() {
       <?php
          if($item->cat_id > 38){
       ?>
             $("#buypdf").show();
       <?php
          }
       ?>
   });
</script>
```

Any tip or advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you include the JQuery file. This should work:

```
$(function(){
   $("#buypdf").show();
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JH7V9/1/)**

You can also do it with pure Javascript:

```
function showDiv(){
    document.getElementById("buypdf").style.display = "block";
};
showDiv();
```

**[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/JH7V9/5/)**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 

I have to add an extra file just for that? I mean, can I not simply add that code somewhere in the same file with <script>?

Comment: If you're using JQuery you have to include the JQuery library. You can do it with javascript and then you don't have to include any file.

Comment: You mean something like this?

<script src="C:\wamp\www\pdfs\libraries\jquery-1.11.1"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
   $("#buypdf").show();
});
</script>

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to show it properly but I can't... Hope you can read it.

Comment: Yes, you can check out the second example with pure Javascript and no need for the JQuery. If you're using JQuery anyway, the first example is more elegant.

Comment: I suppose I was not using JQuery properly.